# Can Overfeat work on ResNet or Inception network architectures

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I am familiar with the principal how Overfeat works to not only classify but also localize an object in an image by only using convolutional layers instead of fully connected layers at the end. However, each tutorial or explanation that I read talks about alexnet or a very basic neural network consisting of a few consecutive convolutional layers followed by 2-3 Fully connected layers to classify an image. However my question goes as follow, is it possible to modify a more complex network such as ResNet or Inception which don't use the standard consecutive convolutional layer techniques as in Alexnet or VGG?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome, and yes. Looking at a very simplified diagram like [this](https://vitalab.github.io/article/images/overfeat/sc2.png), everything to the left of the split "FC" ('fully connected', or 'dense') arrows can be any kind of (what is typically called an) image classification network, such as those in [Keras Applications](https://keras.io/applications/), which includes VGG, ResNet, Inception, Xception, etc. For these kinds of networks, the input is obviously an image, and the output is sometimes called a 'feature map' (although that's a bit silly---have a look at the output and you'll understand---as it's typically far more akin to a post-modernist map than to a cartographic one).

So the answer to your question is yes: put any kind of network you want before the 'overfeat' ending thing, whether custom or otherwise, but know that it's intended to be some general convolutional reductionist model like ResNet, Inception, etc. Any kind of network that takes an image in and spits out a pooled or flattened (1 dimensional) form of a 'feature map' of 3 dimensions is what's apparently intended for this 'overfeat' concept.